# How can I make one line of <table> out of the document flow

Tags: html, css

I want the last <tr> out of the document flow

So I try to use **position: absolute;**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2222231</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="position: absolute;width: 100%;">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but I got it:

[wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lTkh.jpg)

And I want to know How to make **<tr>** get out of the document flow without changing the look and feel

I am trying to achieve this( the last <tr> is **position: absolute;** ):

[i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s44rI.jpg)

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: No,i am using vue

Comment: Positioning on table elements might not work properly cross browser, so another approach could be a `div` inside a table cell that spans the whole table, still, as we don't know what _"without changing the look and feel"_ really means, nor what you actually is trying to do, it is difficult to provide a proper answer.

Comment: can you draw what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border: 1px solid #eaeaea;">
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2222231</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <span>1</span>
          <span>1</span>
            <span>1</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```